# TargetPlatform.linux is not yet supported by the maps plugin on Flutter Web emulator

Tags: flutter

I just built my Flutter app for web and I noticed that the Google maps plugin does not support my OS, Linux.

Answer (score 0):

My app was using the Google Maps for Flutter plugin, which does not support Web “out of the box”.

I added the following to pubspec.yaml:

```
google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.10
google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.1.0+8
```

Also, in the index.html file I added :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=zzzz..zzz,"></script>
```